# SharePoint get multiple value person or group in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint

Id' like to be able to get names from my sharepoint list, these names are added with a peoplepicker, and stored with the field names 'People' and 'Responsible', they are of type 'person or group' in SharePoint. In my Service file I have this:

```
    this.getPeople = function () {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var restQueryUrl = appweburl + "/_api/lists/getByTitle('RisikoAnalyse')/items?$select=People/Title,Responsible/Title&$expand=People/Title,Responsible/Title";
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync({
        url: restQueryUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(data.body));
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            deferred.reject(JSON.stringify(xhr));
        }
    });
    return deferred;
};
```

I get two fields from this, on 'People' which is the multiple value field, and one 'Responsible' where only one value is allowed.
In other words, the first field will have several names in it, and the other will only have one name in it.

In my controller I have:

```
        $.when(SPService.getPeople())
        .done(function (jsonObject) {
            angular.forEach(jsonObject.d.results, function (obj) {
                $scope.peopleList.push({
                    people: obj.People.Title,
                    responsible: obj.Responsible.Title

                });
                //$scope is not updating so force with this command
                if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        });
```

Here I iterate over all objects in 'jsonObject.d.results', and push them to my list of people, 'PeopleList'.

This works for the single value 'Responsible' field, but not the multiple value 'People' field, I'm thinking I have to iterate over the objects inside the 'people' field, but I don't know where or how to do this in an effective way. 
In short: How can I get the multiple values into my peopleList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SharePoint REST service returns *multi-valued* User field in the following JSON format:

```
{
   results: 
      [ { Title: "John Doe"}],
      [ { Title: "Jane Doe"}]
}
```

you could extract people titles as shown below:

```
var peopleTitles = item.People.results.map(function(p){ return p.Title});
```

**Modified example for a controller**

```
angular.forEach(jsonObject.d.results, function (obj) {
     var peopleTitles = typeof obj.People.results != 'undefined' ? obj.People.results.map(function(p){ return p.Title}) : [];
      $scope.peopleList.push({
           people: peopleTitles,
           responsible: obj.Responsible.Title
      });
});
```

Comment: I must say, I had just completed (srsly seconds ago) a workaround, by creating a whole new request for only the multivalued field, and it worked. But now I tried your solution, and it works perfectly with my other fields (hence no new request needed). Thanks a lot!!